# Dataset with name: (XYZ) is missing from datasets

Tags: dashboard, einstein-analytics

I've created a dataset using a dataset recipe, Which is basically a filtered list of opportunities from an existing Opportunity dataset. I updated the JSON dataflow and created a new node to register the data set. The dataflow ran successfully and the new dataset contains the filtered records - So far so good.

I am now trying to edit a standard sales wave dashboard and replace the reference to the standard Opportunity dataset with the new filtered dataset. When I save the change I get the message "Invalid Json - Dataset with name: Filtered_Opportunities1 is missing from datasets. The new dataset is in the same app as the one I am trying to replace.

What may be causing this?

Comment: If you have a wish to receive proper answer then share your code

Comment: This is the node that I have added to the JSON
"Register_Filtered_Opportunities": {
    "action": "sfdcRegister",
    "parameters": {
      "SFDCtoken": "SFDCtoken",
      "name": "Filtered_Opportunities",
      "alias": "Filtered_Opportunities1",
      "source": "Join_OpportunityStage_Previous"
    }
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the second dataset to your sales dashboard. In JSON scroll on the bottom and there is node `"datasets"`. There you can see one dataset. Add the second dataset and you should be good to go.

*An example of having two datasets:*

```
"datasets": [
    {
        "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "label": "Dataset_2",
        "name": "Dataset_2",
        "url": "/services/data/v40.0/wave/datasets/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    },
    {
        "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "label": "Dataset_2",
        "name": "Dataset_2",
        "url": "/services/data/v40.0/wave/datasets/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
]
```